# Выводит сообщение в неправильном порядке

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, vaadin

Я написал чат на ваадине и спринг буте, так вот когда новый пользователь заходит в чат он должен увидеть только последние 10 сообщений, так вот у меня выводит 10 сообщений только в неправильном порядке
У меня здесь выводит

```
Robin: 25
Robin: 23
Robin: 24
Robin: 22
Robin: 21
Robin: 20
Robin: 18
Robin: 19
Robin: 16
Robin: 17
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А должно чтобы вот так чтобы идеально было и по порядку

```
Robin: 16
Robin: 17
Robin: 18
Robin: 19
Robin: 20
Robin: 21
Robin: 22
Robin: 23
Robin: 24
Robin: 25
```

Mainview class

```
public class MainView extends VerticalLayout {
    private final MessagesInfoManager messagesInfoManager;
    private final RestService restService;
    private String username;
    private TextField textField;
    private Message messageLast;


    @Autowired
    public MainView(RestService restService) {
        this.messagesInfoManager = MessageConfigurator.getInstance().getChatMessagesInfoManager();
        addClassName("main-view");
        setSizeFull();
        setDefaultHorizontalComponentAlignment(Alignment.CENTER);

        H1 header = new H1("Vaadin Chat");
        header.getElement().getThemeList().add("dark");

        add(header);

        askUsername();
        this.restService = restService;
    }

    private void askUsername() {
        HorizontalLayout layout = new HorizontalLayout();
        TextField usernameField = new TextField();
        Button startButton = new Button("Start chat");

        layout.add(usernameField, startButton);

        startButton.addClickListener(click -> {
            username = usernameField.getValue();
            remove(layout);
            showChat(username);
        });

        add(layout);
    }

    private void showChat(String username) {
        MessageList messageList = new MessageList();

        List<Message> lasts = restService.getLast();
        for (Message message : lasts) {
            messageList.add(new Paragraph(message.getFromV() + ": " + message.getMessageV()));
        }

        messageLast = lasts.get(lasts.size() - 1);

        add(messageList, createInputLayout(username, messageList));
        expand(messageList);
    }

    private Component createInputLayout(String username, MessageList messageList) {
        HorizontalLayout layout = new HorizontalLayout();
        layout.setWidth("100%");

        TextField messageField = new TextField();
        messageField.addKeyDownListener(Key.ENTER, keyDownEvent -> sender(messageField, messageList));
        Button sendButton = new Button("Send");
        sendButton.addThemeVariants(ButtonVariant.LUMO_PRIMARY);

        layout.add(messageField, sendButton);
        layout.expand(messageField);

        messageField.addFocusListener(event -> {
            for (Message message : messagesInfoManager.getMessagesByUI(getUI())) {
                if (!message.getFromV().equals(username)) {
                    message.setUnread(false);
                    this.restService.updateMessage(message.getId(), message);
                }
            }
        });

        sendButton.addClickListener(click -> sender(messageField, messageList));
        messageField.focus();

        return layout;
    }

    private void sender(TextField textField, MessageList messageList) {
        Message message = new Message(username, textField.getValue());
        restService.saveMessage(message);
        messageLast = message;
        this.textField = textField;
        messagesInfoManager.updateMessageUIInfo(new MessageInfo(messageList, message, this));
        textField.clear();
        textField.focus();
    }

    @Scheduled(fixedDelay = 1000)
    public void scheduleFixedDelayTask() {

        MessageList messageList = new MessageList();

        List<LinkedHashMap> lasts = restService.getUnreadMessages(messageLast.getId());

        for (LinkedHashMap message : lasts) {
            messageList.add(new Paragraph(message.get("fromV") + ": " + message.get("messageV")));
        }



    }
```

MessageRepository

```
 @Query(value = "SELECT * FROM chatmessages ORDER BY time DESC LIMIT 10;", nativeQuery = true)
    List<Message> getLastMessages();
```

Comment: вы сортируете по time, а показываете id? Рядом с id выведите time, поглядите, чему время равно, или сортируйте по айдишникам.

Comment: сделал по айди так же

Comment: Выложите скрин таблицы БД, чтоб было видно все данные.

Comment: Выложил только что

Comment: Ну вроде все понятно. Вы ему в запросе задаете сортировку в обратном порядке. В том же обратном порядке получаете ответ. Но учитывая, что у вас несколько записей создано в одну секунду, то он их выдает по порядку, вот у вас и получилось все вперемешку

Comment: Можете сделать сортировку уже полученных объектов, или переписать запрос, чтоб он правильно сортировал

Comment: Как можно сделать так чтобы он правильно сортировал

Comment: А что мешает по id сортировать? Там ведь у Вас правильная хронология.

Comment: Я делал но не помогает

Comment: И с БД тоже берите последние по id. А то выйдет что берете по времени, а оно может совпасть на границе и возьмете 11-е и 9-е.

Comment: Ну или храните время в милисекундах.

Comment: Покажите как запрос с сортировкой у Вас по id выглядит.

Comment: Чет я не пойму. У вас вот тут `SELECT * FROM chatmessages ORDER BY time DESC LIMIT 10` сортируется по времени по убыванию, а нас скринах сортировано по возрастанию. Вы после получения из бд еще раз сортируете?

Comment: нет только по запросу

Comment: У вас время записывается в форматированном виде и обрезается к секундам. Соответствующе может такое быть что в течении одной секунды вы внесли несколько записей. Сортировку нужно делать по уникальному значению - по id. А у Вас сортировка по времени, которое у Вас повторяется. Если хотите понять почему Вам сортирует в разном порядке одинаковые значения - тогда стоит поинтересоваться такими темами как  многопоточность, синхронность и асинхронность.

Comment: Почему тогда направление сортировки на сайте отличается от сортировки в запросе?

Comment: @V.March это называется устойчивая и не устойчивая сортировки.

Comment: @tym32167 Спасибо за инфу. Раз день уже начался с пополнения копилки проф-знаний - значит пройдет не зря))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если сортировать запросом это будет выглядеть так

```
 @Query(value = 
          "SELECT t.* FROM
             ( SELECT * FROM chatmessages ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 10) t 
           ORDER BY id",   
        nativeQuery=true )
```

Comment: Я добавил картинку посмотрите пожалуйста, это после вашего кода

Comment: тогда поменяйте и сортируйте по id, тот же запрос там только поле поменяйте, я поправил в ответе

Comment: К сожалению та же

Comment: не может быть, выложите скрин базы с этими данными

Comment: Выложил только что

Comment: в запросе в двух местах надо менять поле на id, там где последний order by там тоже id

Comment: Получилось спасибо))) кстати с вами можно перейти в чат хотел насчет запроса кое что спросить

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/103923/discussion-between-z-john-and-grace23).